# php-amqplib heatbeat problem with node use VIP

Tags: php, rabbitmq

when rabbitmq server node use VIP and drift , then client process will hold on and no heartbeat :

```
while (count($this->channel->callbacks)) {
    $this->channel->wait();
}
```

when VIP drift, client will hole on `AbstractConnection::wait_channel()` :

```
list($frame_type, $frame_channel, $payload) = $this->wait_frame($_timeout);
```

because `$_timeout default set 0`

Answer (score 0):

The process was hold on StreamIO.php select():

```
$result = stream_select($read, $write, $except, $sec, $usec);
```

We can avoid it by defining environment variables

```
define('AMQP_WITHOUT_SIGNALS', true);
```